# Get the value of the multiple control using on change in gridview using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have  three controls in my grid view item template of template field one is text box, second is hidden field and the third is label control and also the grid view is dynamically generated, so how to get the value of the particular control on change event of the control and display its value in other dynamic generated control using j query... below is my code

```
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Component_id" HeaderText="Component_id" InsertVisible="False"
                                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Component_id" Visible="False" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Component_Name" HeaderText="Component Name" SortExpression="Component_Name">
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="text_boxtitle" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Component_unit" HeaderText="Component_unit" SortExpression="Component_unit"
                                    Visible="False" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PINTS">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_potency" runat="server" CssClass="txt"
                                            Width="56px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox_potency"
                                            ErrorMessage="*" ValidationExpression="\d{1,9}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Component_unit", "{0}") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField_id" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Component_id", "{0}") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ML">
                                    <ItemStyle />
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="56px"
                                            CssClass="txt"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                                            ErrorMessage="*" ValidationExpression="\d{1,9}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField_Comp_Qty" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Com_Qty") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <RowStyle CssClass="GridItem" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAltItem" />
                            <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What control should fire the onchange event?  and what control is the target?

Comment: I want to get the value of the TextBox_potency and display its value in TextBox1 by on change event of the jquery.

Comment: and what is the ID of your gridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GridView.RowDataBound event to add your jQuery event handler.

Here's an example.  **NOTE** change `gvTest` to match your GridView's ID:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    gvTest.RowDataBound += GvTest_RowDataBound;
}

private void GvTest_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        TextBox TextBox_Potency = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBox_Potency");
        TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBox1");
        TextBox_Potency.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "$('#" + TextBox1.ClientID + "').val($(this).val());");
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to get its value in jquery code, because my requirement is some thing like that

Comment: And the id of the Grid View is GridView2

Comment: it does use jquery to set the value, see `TextBox_Potency.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "$('#" + TextBox1.ClientID + "').val($(this).val());"); `, but the handler is added in .NET code-behind